# Multiple rounds of bipartite matching problem

Tags: graphs, bipartite-matching

I have a set of investors (say n), and a set of startups (say m). At the start, I have all the investors say either yes or no to the startup (which corresponds to whether they want to interact with them or not).

Now, I have to conduct a networking event of r rounds considering this scenario. In each round, I match investors with startups they want to meet (one investor with one startup). I want to conduct the rounds such that the sum of the startups they met, across all investors, is maximum.

Now, if r=1, this reduces to the maximum bipartite matching problem. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this for r>1? I have been thinking along the lines of having the source and sink edge capacities to be r instead of 1, but I am unable to prove that this works.

Comment: Have you searched for "weighted bipartite matching"?

Comment: Forgive me, but it's not obvious to me how this reduces to the weighted bipartite matching problem. I need a union of r matchings finally, so how would you visualize that being guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by a mild extension of the standard reduction to network flow: increase the weight of the edges touching the source and the sink to $r$. Any integer flow corresponds to a union of $r$ matchings:

- An integer flow corresponds to a bipartite graph of maximum degree $r$.
- We can complete this bipartite graph to an $r$-regular bipartite graph by adding vertices and edges:

  1. Add vertices so that both sides have the same number of vertices.
  2. If the graph is not $r$-regular, then there must be two vertices $x,y$ (one on each side) with degree less than $r$. Add $r$ new vertices $x_1,\ldots,x_r$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_r$ to each side (respectively), and connect all of them except $x_1$ and $y_1$. Connect $x$ to $y_1$ and $y$ to $x_1$. This reduces the overall deficiency of the graph $\sum_v (r - \deg(v))$ by 1.
- Repeated applications of Hall's theorem shows that the new graph can be decomposed into $r$ perfect matchings.
- Restricting these matchings to the original vertices and edges, we obtain a union of $r$ matchings.

Schrijver mentions this problem in his Combinatorial Optimization (Vol 1):

> **Corollary 21.4b.** *Let $G = (V,E)$ be a bipartite graph and let $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Then the maximum size of the union of $k$ matchings is equal to the minimum value of $k|V \setminus X| + |E(X)|$ taken over $X \subseteq V$.*

This follows by an application of the min cut max flow theorem.